Convert panel- into time-series data using Sqlite
I have the following table scores
CREATE TABLE "scores" (
    "fight_id"  INTEGER,
    "judge_id"   INTEGER,
    "fighter_id" INTEGER,
    "round"   INTEGER,
    "n_points" INTEGER
);

A small sample of my data looks as follows:
5691    9   1866    1   10
5691    9   896     1   9
5691    9   1866    2   9
5691    9   896     2   10
5691    9   1866    3   9
5691    9   896     3   10

Currently, the data is stored as panel/longitudinal data.
I want to create a query that gives the following output
5691    9   1   10   9
5691    9   2   9   10
5691    9   3   9   10

I know I need to group-by fight_id, judge_id and round, but how do I obtain the desired output.

Short Answer
Unfortunately, sqlite does not natively support pivoting. But you can try to "tinker" with a query with the [case][1] statement. A hardcode version of the query you are looking for might look like this:
SELECT
    fight_id,
    judge_id,
    round,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fighter_id = 1866 THEN n_points END) AS fgt_1866_pt,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fighter_id = 896 THEN n_points END) AS fgt_896_pt
FROM scores
GROUP BY fight_id, judge_id, round
ORDER BY fight_id, judge_id, round;

Long Answer
SQLite does not natively support dynamic pivoting. However, you can work around this limitation by generating a dynamic query, especially if the fighter_id values are not known in advance or change frequently.

Select all fighter_id:
SELECT DISTINCT fighter_id FROM scores;

Generate a query


fighter_ids = [...];
columns = ", ".join([
    f"MAX(CASE WHEN fighter_id = {fid} THEN n_points END) AS fgt_{fid}_pt"
    for fid in fighter_ids
])

query = f"""
SELECT
    fight_id,
    judge_id,
    round,
    {columns}
FROM scores
GROUP BY fight_id, judge_id, round
ORDER BY fight_id, judge_id, round;
"""

*sorry i had a probleme with the formatter
